# Getting current activity when a workflow instance loads from persistent store in WF 4.0

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I've still been trying to wrap my head around some workflow issues we've been having. I'm using Workflow foundation 4.0 and I need to get the current activity of an instance when I load it from persistence. I tried using tracking, but that does not get called when the instance is loaded.

I'd like to avoid having to persist this information myself if at all possible.

Do you have any idea about how to do this?

Regards,
 Anže

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know using tracking is the only way to monitor which activity starts and stops. Using a workflow extension deriving from PersistenceParticipant you can save the data as part of the workflow itself. Keep in mind that the could be multiple active asynchronous activities when a workflow is persisted.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265315/windows-workflow-persistence-data-vs-2010-rc-net-4-0) for how to do so.

Comment: I've ended up doing it with bookmarks, because I didn't want to persist this tracking information along. I hoped there will be a method somwhere like "GetCurrentActivity".